# pgfplots: math expressions of variables in axis style

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfkeys, pgfmath

I would like to use a calculated value of pgf variable `exp(\pgfplots@data@xmin)`

This is a concrete example what I need

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\makeatletter
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xtick={1.1, 
            %\pgfplots@data@xmin % <- this works without the line below
            exp(\pgfplots@data@xmin) % <- I need this
        }
    ]
    \addplot {exp(x)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\makeatother
```

Comment: `\pgfplots@data@xmin ` expands to `1Y1.0e2147483645]` which doesn't look like any kind of number? what value to you want to pass to `xtick` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's a number in IEEE format from fpu library output

Comment: @percusse it is? oh learn something every day, what does Y mean?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The first digit is a "sign flag", `Y` is a separator which is less likely to suffer from active catcodes than any special char, the number in-between is a number in scientific format and the final `]` is the number terminator. The sign flag `1` means "positive number". This format is only used for PGF's floating point unit with the purpose to allow an efficient access to previous results. The number as such is the biggest possible value in the tex FPU, at least if one does not use lualatex (which has its own parser module). Disclaimer: I invented it for the purpose of pgfplots

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger I suppose I could always read the manual:-)

Comment: well, the might provide something about the facts ... but not the background information and probably not in that concentrated form. And I suppose that this Y-format is not really worth to parse lots of manuals unless you really need it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is what you want

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\makeatletter
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xtick={1.1,\pgfplots@data@xmin},
        xticklabels={$\exp(1.1)$,$\exp(\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplots@data@xmin})$}
    ]
    \addplot{exp(x)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or `xticklabel={$\exp(\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick})$}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Good point. My brain was short.